# How to get the date difference in seconds ,in perl

Tags: perl

I have two dates , (they are datetime objects).

How can i get the  difference between these two dates, in seconds ?

```
my $givenDate1 =  DateTime->new(
      year       => 1982,
      month      => 10,
      day        => 25,
      hour       => 7,
      minute     => 19,
      second     => 35,

      time_zone  => 'UTC',
  );
my $givenDate2 =  DateTime->new(
      year       => 1982,
      month      => 10,
      day        => 25,
      hour       => 7,
      minute     => 20,
      second     => 50,

      time_zone  => 'UTC',
  );
```

It should return the time difference as  75 secs

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=perl+datetime+difference

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, thanks for the reply.But it won't give entire difference into  seconds only

Comment: Does it have to be DateTime objects? Because with Time::Piece objects it would be as easy as `($givenDate1 - $givenDate2)->seconds`

Comment: @DeVadder, thanks for the reply.But It will give only the difference between  seconds only.Not cosider others like minutes difference, hour difference....So for my question it will give only 15 seconds as answer  not 75 seconds

Comment: @Linto Yes, that is true for DateTime objects. What is the reason i asked if that was a requirement. If the two dates where Time::Piece objects, using the probably already installed Time::Piece module, it would work and correctly give 75 seconds. But in case your script uses DataTime at some other places or is part of a bigger project, it might not be a good idea to switch.

Comment: @DeVadder.Just leave the datetime object.give the example code the way you mentioned

Comment: @DeVadder,Thanks for your responses.But "ikegami" give the solution what i exactly wants

Comment: There are reasons why this is harder than it seems it should be. Some of DateTime's units are variable (number of days in a month, hours in a day in many timezones etc), and using `-` to get a `DateTime::Duration` object enables you to do things such as add a month or subtract a day. This is a valid view of dates and times, but different to what the OP wants in this case, so the solution is to convert to a simpler unit first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
say $givenDate2->epoch - $givenDate1->epoch;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my $givenDate1 =  DateTime->new(
      year       => 1982,
      month      => 10,
      day        => 25,
      hour       => 7,
      minute     => 19,
      second     => 35,

      time_zone  => 'UTC',
  );
my $givenDate2 =  DateTime->new(
      year       => 1982,
      month      => 10,
      day        => 25,
      hour       => 7,
      minute     => 20,
      second     => 50,

      time_zone  => 'UTC',
  );
say $givenDate1->subtract_datetime_absolute($givenDate2)->seconds
```

Outputs:

```
75
```

One minute is not always 60 seconds, so you can't convert a duration of 1 minute 15 seconds to 75 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a good solution using `Time::Piece`.

```
my $format = '%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y';

my $date2 = "$mes $dia $h:$m:$s $ano"; #'Aug 30 10:53:38 2013'
my $date1 = strftime($format, localtime(time())); #'Aug 30 10:53:38 2013'

my $diff = Time::Piece->strptime($date1, $format) - Time::Piece->strptime($date2, $format);

print "\n $date1 --> $date2 = $diff seconds.";
```

Adapt the format to your needs.